# MessageBox.Show error in C#

Tags: c#, messagebox

I'm trying to compile this code but it gives me 2 errors about MessageBox.

It's a simple program with 3 variables. plus 2 Text boxes (box1, box2) and a button (btn).

I'm trying to add numbers in box1 with box2 and show the result as a variable named "outcome" in a Message Box.

Error 1

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(string)' has some invalid arguments

Error 2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Here's the code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         int str1 = int.Parse(box1.Text);
         int str2 = int.Parse(box2.Text);
         int outcome;
         outcome = 0;
         outcome = str1 + str2;
         MessageBox.Show(outcome.ToString);
    }
}
```

Comment: the last error message means that you're not calling the function. `outcome.ToString` <-- missing parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
MessageBox.Show(outcome.ToString);
```

to

```
MessageBox.Show(outcome.ToString());
```

Method group means the method, think of it as a function pointer. You can't print the method `ToString`, you want to print the resulting string and you get that by evaluating the method with `()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the first exception it's a method you miss `()` *it's not a property*

```
 MessageBox.Show(outcome.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo:
use () after ToString ----> outcome.ToString()